# Reading the entries in a loop and removing the duplicate entries using XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSL and I have a confusion whether we can read the data in a xml tag and then store it in an array or something and then remove the duplicate by using distinct option.

eg.

```
<local>
  <ID>
    <fruit>apple</fruit>
    <fruit>orange</fruit>
  </ID>
  <ID>
    <fruit>apple</fruit>
    <fruit>mango</fruit>
  </ID>
</local>
```

In this, I'm reading through the Local as the loop initiator and needs to read all the ID's underneath it and display the fruits. In this case, I dont there are 4 different fruits are there and one is duplicated, so I just want to display the unique entries of those and display.  Is there any possibility of getting this done using XSLT?

```
<xsl:for-each select="Local">  
  <xsl:variable name="fruits">
    <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(ID/fruit)">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFruitByName" match="fruit" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
   "/*/*/fruit
     [generate-id()
     =
      generate-id(key('kFruitByName', .)[1])
     ]"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<local>
    <ID>
        <fruit>apple</fruit>
        <fruit>orange</fruit>
    </ID>
    <ID>
        <fruit>apple</fruit>
        <fruit>mango</fruit>
    </ID>
</local>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<fruit>apple</fruit>
<fruit>orange</fruit>
<fruit>mango</fruit>
```

**Explanation**: Using the **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*/fruit" group-by=".">
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the same correct result is produced**:

```
<fruit>apple</fruit>
<fruit>orange</fruit>
<fruit>mango</fruit>
```

Comment: Thank You Dimitre, But I want to display in a UI with only the values, when I tried the sameway, Its not letting me to get the exact results. as expected. It displays as null value there and no outputs are getting displayed

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I did get the concept, but now the problem for me, is. 
    <Local id="1" type="Primary">
     -<summary Date="23-02-12">
      -<fruit>apple</fruit>
      -<fruit>Orange</fruit>
      </summary>
      </local>
      <Local id="2" type="Primary">
     -<summary Date="23-02-12">
      -<fruit>apple</fruit>
      -<fruit>mango</fruit>
      </summary>
      </local>

So in this case, I'm able to get into local, but not able to read the data. Could you please help me in that?
     </local>

Comment: @user1227273: Please, edit the question, or, better, ask a new question -- comments are not convenient for formatting code. Also, the thext in your last comment isn't a well-formed XML document. You also need to provide the exact wanted result --whether it should be a copy of the nodes, or just their text, or HTML.