# Storing into a variable and displaying the unique entries using XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In that, I want to display only the unique fruit entries in it. Here is the XML tag what I'm using for parsing

```
<main>
<local id="1" type="Primary"> 
-<summary Date="23-02-12"> 
-<fruit>apple</fruit> 
-<fruit>Orange</fruit> 
</summary> 
</local> 
<local id="2" type="Primary"> 
-<summary Date="23-02-12"> 
-<fruit>apple</fruit> 
-<fruit>mango</fruit> 
</summary> 
</local> 
</main>
```

The expected result should be in the below format

```
<fruit>apple</fruit>
<fruit>Orange</fruit>
<fruit>Mango</fruit>
```

Here are the code snippet what I'm trying to use

```
<xsl:for-each select="main/local">  
<xsl:for-each select="symbol/fruit">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="fruit[not(.=$fruit)]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I'm not getting any output display for this, Can you please help me how can I remove this duplicate redundancy from here.? Thank You in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading the entries in a loop and removing the duplicate entries using XSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406061/reading-the-entries-in-a-loop-and-removing-the-duplicate-entries-using-xsl)

Comment: You already asked a similar question and got a corect answer. Why are you now asking essentially the same question? Please, read more about Muenchian grouping (follow the link in the answer to the first question) and grouping in general. It isn't good for you or for anybody to slightly alter the XML document and ask what amounts to essentially the same question again. You also have problems with your understanding of XPath. Please, ask new, specific XPath questions -- like: "What XPath expression selects all `fruit` elements in the XML document?"

Answer (score 0):

To do this in XSLT1.0 you can make use of a technique called 'Meunchian' grouping. First you define a key to 'look-up' the **fruit** elements based on the value

```
<xsl:key name="fruit" match="fruit" use="." />
```

Then, to get the unique fruit names, you match **fruit** elements that happen to be the first fruit element in the key (and to check two nodes are the same the generate-id() method is used)

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
    select="//fruit[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fruit', .)[1])]" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="fruit" match="fruit" use="." />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates 
         select="//fruit[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fruit', .)[1])]" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<fruit>apple</fruit>
<fruit>Orange</fruit>
<fruit>mango</fruit>
```